# Ninject 2.0 incompatibility with Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ninject-2

I'm dev'ing an MVC 2 website targeting .NET 4.0 and using Ninject 2.0 (dev box running Win 7 64 pro).  All is going well on the dev side, I really enjoyed using Ninject and it works a charm.

Until I deploy it to the server.  Once I deploy the app to the server (a virtual machine running Win Server 2008 R2 x64, IIS 7.5) the ninject binding appear to simply not happen.  I was first getting a null reference exception on the Logger that I was calling in OnApplicationStarted, I manually bound that and I got another null reference exception the very next time the code called for an injected component. Manually changing that one pushes the problem down the line.

I'm not getting any errors at all locally, and I'm not getting errors in the event log other than the null reference exceptions on injected components.

I have already verified that the server has .Net 4.0, MVC 2's dll, both Ninject DLLs and the DLLs of all my components.  I was compiling against "any cpu" as well, in release mode.

Any ideas or known bugs w/ the platform I've described?

I'd post source code except that I figured it's not relevant since it's working locally unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ninject works fine on Server 2008 R2. If you are experiencing a difference in functionality between your machine and the server, then something is different in your setup. There is no way to help you with the information you have provided so far. Please create a sample project that exhibits the issue and it will be a lot easier to help you.

-Ian